# ElementNotVisibleException on clearly visible element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to do some UI-testing with Selenium and PhantomJS from my server (in Python). For my first test I want to click the login button. So I wrote the following:

```
driver = self.driver
driver.get(BASE_URI)
print driver.page_source
loginButton = driver.find_element_by_id('login')
loginButton.click()
```

This gives me an `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"`. It is weird, because it is clearly visible both in the browser and in the html which I print on the third line:

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;">
    <a id="login" href="/login/" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> Login met LinkedIn
    </a>
</div>
```

Does anybody know why I get this exception, and how I can solve this?

[EDIT]

Here is the full source of the html: http://pastebin.com/TuUKC55X . As you can see no iframes, no loading of elements. Plain and simple bootstrap html.

Comment: is there any iframe?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas - No, there are no iframes on the page

Comment: for fun... get the `outerHTML` of `loginButton` and make sure it's the element you think it is. You could also use CSS Selector "#login" and get the count and make sure it's 1. Is there some AJAX or other code that modifies the state of that button after the page loads? You could wait for element to be visible.

Comment: Just for the the test try another browser, like Chrome or Firefox as WebDriver. Make sure there are no double #login ids inserted on the page by JavaScript.

Comment: This runs on a headless Linux server, but I also tried it on OSX with Firefox and there I've got the same problems..